# Is it possible to display the placeholder on input fields over 2 rows?

Tags: angular, angular-material, placeholder

I want to have the placeholder-text on Angular Material Input Fields shown over 2 lines. Is that possible? If the placeholder is too long then it is cut. I don't want to make very wide fields for number inputs up to 99.

Below you can see how I use the placeholder.

```html
          <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'inputNumber'">
              <input
                id="{{element.elementId}}"
                #focusable
                matInput
                type="number"
                [(ngModel)]="element.value"
                [placeholder]="element.placeholder"
                (focus)="setFocusDurchTastatur(sektion)"
                (blur)="disableFocusDurchTastatur(sektion)" >
          </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Comment: I achieved it with: `white-space: pre-wrap !important;
  line-height: 15px !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;` ... propably ugly but it works ok

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
.mat-form-field-label {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But there is another problem. The Input Field itself is now overlapped by the placeholder. I tried to set the height, margin etc. but is does not work to get the input field below of the placeholder. does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: `mat-form-field-label` is `position: absolute` so you can try manipulant `top` value. 
Unfortunately, there are a large number of combinations. I hope the `top` will work.

Comment: I can set the top to 0px for example. The placeholder-text goes up but it is cut on the top. :( I tried to manipulate the wrapper and the input Tag itself but nothing work.